Searching for a sci Fi story with demon summoning
So I'm not sure if this is one story or I'm conflating two stories, but:
A demon describes hell, and says that they can conjure anything they want there. Someone once conjured a gold rectangular prism 40 miles long. They're constantly burning stuff because they can conjure stuff but can't get rid of stuff.
A female protagonist on a space station summons a demon, as demon summoning is part of the scientific body of knowledge of humanity. It used to be secret, but them it got published. I think the demon is freed at some point and continues helping the protagonist? And they have to terraform Mars?
This was a novel, which I read years and years ago. (Can't give an exact date, sorry)
I think it's all one story, I'm not conflating things - part of the method of terraforming Mars was ordering the demon to conjure atmosphere. The demon had a limit of how much it could make at any one time, so it made batches of air, again and again.
In hell, the demons could conjure computers only if they understood them well enough? So since most physical things could be conjured at will by any demons, currency was something more intangible? Can't quite remember, maybe books and music?
So the main character pays the demon by giving them a usb containing books and music.
Also, the main character had a rival, who was also female, I think.

Well, I just turned 30. Does that help?

So, probably sometime after 2010?
